# Loopback MySQL to MongoDB migration with relationship

Tags: mysql, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a MySQL well structured schema maintained with proper relationship in MySQL in Loop-back, I wish to convert same schema in MongoDB maintaining relationship in Embedded as followed by Mongo. Is their any tool I can run in Loopback so it converts same schema and relationship in MongoDb.

I have done simple database name changes in `model-config.json` to implement/convert it in MOngoDB. Is this right approach? Please suggest for migration to MOngoDb.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good idea to me. MongoDB is not a drop-in replacement for MySQL. When you really want to benefit from MongoDB you need to manually evaluate how you deal with your data. When you try to use MongoDB as if it were an SQL database, you will likely suffer from all of its weaknesses and not make use of any of its strengths.

Comment: Did you create your models via `slc loopback:model`? You should have the relations for the schema already defined in the model configurations at `common/models/*`.